# How can I find the file that's causing a Django error? Getting "Invalid filter: 'add_class'" but no file

Tags: python, django, traceback, shrink

So the site itself runs without any errors that I can find.

I have shrink installed and I'm trying to run collect static.  In the process of running it gives me a TemplateSyntaxError.  Every file in the traceback is a site-package file and I'm not sure how to go about finding where the error is coming from.  Are there any tools that will check that and let me see where/how it's processing so I can perhaps have a way to find where the error is coming from?

This is my traceback:

```
> You have requested to collect static files at the destination location
> as specified in your settings.
> 
> This will overwrite existing files! Are you sure you want to do this?
> 
> Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
> 
> 0 static files copied, 1249 unmodified. Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "tools/manage.py", line 16, in <module>
>     execute_manager(settings)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 459, in execute_manager
>     utility.execute()   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 382, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 196, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 232, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 371, in handle
>     return self.handle_noargs(**options)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shrink/management/commands/collectstatic.py",
> line 58, in handle_noargs
>     templates.add(get_template(pjoin(dirpath, f)))   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 145, in get_template
>     template, origin = find_template(template_name)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 134, in find_template
>     source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 42, in __call__
>     return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 48, in load_template
>     template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)   File
> "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 156, in get_template_from_string
>     return Template(source, origin, name)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 125, in __init__
>     self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 153, in compile_string
>     return parser.parse()   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 267, in parse
>     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 214, in do_extends
>     nodelist = parser.parse()   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 267, in parse
>     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 189, in do_block
>     nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 246, in parse
>     filter_expression = self.compile_filter(token.contents)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 346, in compile_filter
>     return FilterExpression(token, self)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 557, in __init__
>     filter_func = parser.find_filter(filter_name)   File "/home/adam/pyprojects/trekadoo-web/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 352, in find_filter
>     raise TemplateSyntaxError("Invalid filter: '%s'" % filter_name) django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'add_class'
```

add_class is used hundreds of time throughout the project.

Comment: Try using grep or ack to search for that string?

Comment: `add_class` is available in django-widget-tweaks...is that used in your project?

Comment: @Wooble I did grep for add_class, it's used hundreds of places, and works in the majority of them.

Comment: @Brandon yes, v1.3 is installed, widget_tweaks is added in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Ok, so in PyCharm I ran "manage.py collectstatic" in debug mode as a python script and put break points around in the django core files mentioned in the traceback.  I was able to then go back through the frames until I found the file it was referencing.  Why that file wouldn't be listed in the traceback is beyond me.  But that file was missing a {% load widget_tweaks %}  Added and fixed.

Comment: so put it as an answer, it's the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so in PyCharm I ran "manage.py collectstatic" in debug mode as a python script and put break points around in the django core files mentioned in the traceback.

I was able to then go back through the frames until I found the file it was referencing. Why that file wouldn't be listed in the traceback is beyond me. But that file was missing a

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

Added and fixed.